# Альтернатива модульному программированию

Tags: c, модульность, c++

Какие существуют альтернативы, разделению кода на модули? То есть интересует вопрос в подходе к проектированию самой архитектуры, а не использование каких либо особенностей конкретной среды разработки или оптимизации кода(вроде удаления шаблонов).
Например .h .cpp в С++.

> Основная цель: повышение скорости
> компиляции.
>
> Дополнительная цель:
> удобство использования.

[@Flammable](/users/10467/flammable)

Comment: Никаких? Держать всё вместе с зависимостями в голове для проекта размером от 1000 строк кода чревато дикими ошибками.

А зачем вам альтернатива? Чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Интересно, что вам ответят.
На самом деле модульная организация проекта как раз и используется для:
- повышение скорости компиляции за счет раздельной компиляции только измененных модулей,
- удобства использования (в том числе, удобство отладки, удобство повторного использования).
Придумать что-то другое - нобелевская премия...

Comment: Ну просто Flammable сказал что это устаревший подход.
Мне кажется что базой всё равно будет раздельная компиляция, только выполненная как то по другому.

Comment: - использовать побольше готового кода в виде модулей (они будут только линковаться).
- минимизировать код (не уменьшать, а именно минимизировать, то есть знать особенности компилятора на очень низком уровне).
- использовать прекомпилированые заголовки
- перейти на скриптовые языки - там часто вообще никакой компиляции:)

Comment: @Flammable: ваш ход.

Comment: @manking, а мне вот интересно - что за мега-проекты такие, вызывающие подобные вопросы :) У меня самый большой (C/C++), человек на 7 программистов, компилючился минут 20-30 при полной пересборке под одну target, но это вообще не повод...

Comment: @manking, а что Вы называете модулем?

Единицу компиляции или "экзешник"? Если "экзешник", то что бы Вы считали модулем для скриптового языка?

Если говорить о пространстве имен (внешних ссылок), то динамически загружаемая .so (.dll) это модуль?

Из Вашего вопроса совершенно не очевидно - что именно Вы бы хотели обсудить.

Comment: @Flammable

Прекомпилированные заголовки это не "модули". Модулем может быть dll/so/lib/a

вспомнился ещё один метод ускорения - распараллеливание компиляции. в случае make (как наиболее часто используемого в линуксах) - опция `-j4` (где 4 - это кол-во потоков-процессов, можно подбирать. для 8ядерного может быть оптимально 9).

Comment: @avp
Ну модуль это и единица компиляции как .cpp, так и в некотором роде .dll.
То есть там где хранится определение-тело функций(правильно?).

В начале вопроса я хотел узнать о новых веяниях в модульном программировании.
А из ответа  KoVadim - хотелось бы понять на счёт скриптовых языков.

Мне казалось смысл скрипта - это открыть часть кода для редактирования фанатами игр.
Вопрос: можно ли в .h файле объявить функции, затем как то указать что они определены в скрипте?

@KoVadim 
в vs называется "многопроцессорная компиляция", с 5 мин. в debug, снижает время до 30 сек (4+4 виртуальных ядра).

Comment: не нужно делать полную перекомпиляцию. 

Либо перейти на язык, который компилирует быстро. Делфи (да, у него быстрый компилятор, правда не знаю, как с последними версиями) или Go.

а говоря о скриптах, я имею ввиду питон/перл/руби (выбрать по вкусу) без плюсов. Хотя в питоне некая компиляция все же есть.

Comment: Да нет. Я просто зашел сюда, решил  по отвечать на вопросы. 

А тут "Раздельная компиляция - зло." 
Я "Ё моё! Только только второй рефакторинг завершил. Всё делал по правилам. И опять всё не так."

Сейчас понимаю, что вопрос довольно глупый.  
Быстрее компиляции отдельного модуля ничего быть не может. А иначе этот модуль следует еще разбивать на отдельные модули если получится. Всё остальное уже не процесс компиляции, а вставка готового скомпилированного кода.

Comment: Если кому интересно, то для нового стандарта (который `C++1y`) есть `proposal` [включить в `C++` **модули,**](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/modules-update-on-work-in-progress-doug-gregor) что, судя по всему, должно ускорить и время компиляции и вообще сделать жизнь проще.

Comment: Довольно интересная тема.
Оказывается при включении только

    #include <iostream>

Происходит включение 1.161 миллиона символов кода.

Только информации нет. В visual - module export header не являются ключевыми словами. В gcc вроде тоже.
vs12 - warning C4237: ключевое слово "export" пока не поддерживается, но зарезервировано для использования в будущем

А смысл в чём? Цеплять из .h файлов только определенные "public" интерфейсы(функции)?
Можно комментарий "Котик____хочет____кушать(8 часов назад)" переместить в ответ? Мне кажется это правильный ответ на вопрос хотя и не информативный.

Answer (score 3):

Вы думали о инкапсуляции?:) подумайте. Я бы например не хотел видеть в своей программе реализацию printf(). Раздельная компиляция повышает скорость раз в десять, если у вас 10 модулей и один вы исправили, то компилируется только исправленный. Эта архитектура не остаток от прадедов в наследство, это опытом и десятилетиями проверенный и наработанный метод. В конце концов, а если часть программы будет разрабатывать кто то другой? Все в одном месте?

Comment: По секрету. Может вам просто лень писать Makefile?:))